# Look inside contents of list stored inside dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, list, search, dictionary

```
list1 = []
list2 = []
list3 = []

elecStorage = []

elective = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
prereq = []

dict1 = {
1: SEM1period1, 2: SEM1period2,
3: SEM1period3, 4: SEM1period3,
5: SEM1period5, 6: SEM1period6,
7: SEM1period7, 8: SEM1period8
}

for key in dict1:
    if len(dict1) < 1:
        list1.append("Free Period")
    elif key in list1:
        break
    elif key in elective:
        elecStorage.append(key)
    elif key in prereq:
        list1.append(key)

print elecStorage
print list1
```

Note: SEM1period1 through SEM1period8 are all lists, passed earlier as arguments.

What this snippet should do is search through each element in each list of the dictionary dict1, and compare it the contents of other lists like elective and prereq, and then append it to either list1 or elecStorage. Though ["a", "b", "c", "d"] should all be appended to elecStorage when I tell it to print out it doesn't... why is this?

Thanks in advance. Any questions, I'll clarify. I'm a bit of a novice so take it easy on me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made many assumptions on your objective, but this might at least help:

```
for key, dlist in dict1.items():
    if not dlist:
        list1.append("Free Period")
        continue
    for item in dlist:
        if item in list1:
            continue
        if item in elective:
            elecStorage.append(item)
        elif item in prereq:
            list1.append(item)
```

Comment: Can you explain this chunk to me?